# Display similar words

Tags: javascript, php

I have a table that contains 2 fields, private and personal names, i need to create a search page that will allow to search this names. The catch is that i need to detect typo's too.

*For example:* searching for Jonh will find John.

So i'm trying to get the results with LIKE and then split the string to characters and count the amount of letters that are the same in JS loop. So if 4 or more chars are the same, i'm printing the string. But for some reason this is not always working, maybe there's a better way to do this?

`SELECT first_name FROM Employees WHERE first_name like '%{$first_name}%'`

And then JS:

```
var counted = 0;
var inputFromUser = "some input".split('');
var resultCharsArray = "<?php echo $result;?>".split('');
for (var i = 0; i < inputFromUser.length; i++) {
    if ($.inArray(inputFromUser[i],resultCharsArray) { counted++; }
}

if (counted >= 4) {
    console.log("<?php echo $result;?>");
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Yep, there is a better way of doing this.

You can use [SOUNDS LIKE](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-sounds_like-function.php) . And then you won't need to run any JS.

`SELECT first_name FROM Employees WHERE first_name SOUNDS LIKE 'Jonh'`

Comment: Quite possibly my favorite answer since joining the site